# Elasticsearch 1.5.2 shared allocation stuck

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with the following specs (es v 1.5.2):

- 3 nodes with RAM: 32GB, CPU cores: 8 each
- 63 total indices = 32 marvel + 1 kibana + 30 data
- 366 total shards = (32 marvel + 1 kibana + 150 data)* 1 replica
- 959,231,444 total docs
- 588.38GB total data
- ES_HEAP_SIZE=16g

I have successfully **deleted around 200 empty indices** and restarted the cluster- normally the allocation take 1 hour to finish but now it is over 12 hours and still I have 183 unassigned shared.

Also, I can see that node1 have only 6 shards allocated to it- most of the data shards is separated between node2 and node3. I tried to restart node1 and still got the same situation. why isn't it taking more shards to it?

What could be the problem and how can I make the allocation go faster and finish?

Comment: You probably did not [disable shard allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/setup-upgrade.html#rolling-upgrades) before restarting your nodes, did you? It's a good practice to do it, whenever you have to restart your nodes in order to prevent unnecessary shard re-allocation.

Comment: I didnt, but why it is taking so long now? before it was faster... And how can I make it faster now? It seems not normal to wait 12+ hours for shared allocation to finish.

Comment: Probably because between the time you shut down one node and brought it back up, some new documents have been indexed and now the primary and replica shards are not in synch anymore ([read more here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_delaying_shard_allocation.html)). Unfortunately, you can't make it faster now, you just have to wait for it to finish. Next time just make sure to properly disable shard allocation during the restart and re-enable it afterwards.

Comment: yeah, I have new documents indexing all the time... So it is not so strange that it takes 12+ hours now?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can use the command `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards` in order to get some insights into which shards still need to be allocated.

Comment: yeah, I see them with plugin head... Thank you.

Comment: How many are still unassigned after 12 hours?

Comment: I deleted the empty indices yesterday, went home, and now I have unassigned 183/366 shards.

Comment: Weird, as it's exactly the half which are not assigned. Are you sure all your nodes are up? Can you explain exactly the sequence of actions you did yesterday?

Comment: I can see now that node1 have only 6 shards allocated to it- most of the data shards is separated between node2 and node3. I tried to restart node1 and still got the same thing. why isnt it taking more shards to it?

Comment: Can you explain exactly the sequence of actions you did yesterday?

Comment: Oh, missed your previous comment. Nothing that I didnt wrote I think, just deleted 200 empty indices, saw it happening and restart the cluster without disabling allocation.

Comment: And to the best of your knowledge, before your restarted all nodes were all the shards allocated equally among the three nodes?

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with the output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find a solution- I just [update indices settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) by setting the number of the replica for all of the indices to 0, then the cluster health turned green and finally updated the settings again by setting the number of the replica for all of the indices back to 1.

The cluster started to allocate the shards normally (to node1 also).